# Django Form Initial Value not Showing

Tags: django, django-forms

I want to make a form to edit a model object, with the initial data being the original data (before the change), but it doesn't show,
it was just a blank form

models.py:

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

forms.py:

```
class EmployeeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name']
        labels = {'first_name' : 'First Name:', 'last_name' : 'Last Name:' }
        input_attrs = {'class' : 'form-control'}
        widgets = {
            'first_name' : forms.TextInput(attrs=input_attrs), 
            'last_name' : forms.TextInput(attrs=input_attrs)}
```

views.py:

```
def edit(request, id):
    employee = Employee.objects.get(id=id)
    data = {
        'first_name' : employee.first_name,
        'last_name' : employee.last_name,
    }
    form = EmployeeForm(request.POST or None, initial=data, instance=employee)
    if (form.is_valid and request.method == 'POST'):
        form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/form/')
    response = {'employee_form' : EmployeeForm, 'employee':employee}
    return render(request, 'editemployee.html', response)
```

editemployee.html:

```
<div class="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <form action="" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {% for form in employee_form %}
                {{ form.label }}
                {{ form }} 
                <br>
            {% endfor %}
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can anyone please tell me where I went wrong? I've tried so many things but to no avail. The form works fine, but the initial data doesn't show.

Answer (score 1):

Editing an existing record, no initial data is needed, it comes from the model instance.

```
form = EmployeeForm(request.POST or None, instance=employee)
```

If you need default data in those fields, you can add it in the model.

Comment: thank you, i have tried that too before trying to use initial, but it still wouldn't show...

Comment: Is the initial data being set from the values in the model ? I would guess that is what the `'first_name' : employee.first_name,` is doing.  This seems like it would set the same value as the employee instance.